# Copiar contenido de un docx a otro en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

tengo dudas con este código. Mi objetivo es hacer un script en python que busque el primer estilo "Heading 1" en un archivo docx, luego escriba todo el contenido que sigue al "Heading 1" incluyendo el encabezado en un nuevo docx, hasta encontrar un nuevo encabezado, en cuyo punto dejará de copiar el contenido en el nuevo archivo, para crear otro archivo docx y repetir el proceso de copia del nuevo "Heading 1" y el contenido que le sigue. De momento, el script copia parte del contenido y algunos de los estilos etc, pero tiene problemas con las celdas/columnas y no consigue el mismo estilo exacto que el original, siendo mi objetivo que el contenido copiado sea exactamente el mismo que el original, mismo formato,estilos ,etc.... Además el original puede tener algunos estilos personalizados, por si ayuda saberlo. Gracias de antemano

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("example_doc.docx")

count = 1

for i, para in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
    
    if para.style.name.startswith("Heading 1"):
        original = docx.Document("example_doc.docx")
        copy = docx.Document()
        for style in original.styles:
            if style.type == docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH:
                style_exists = False
                for dest_style in copy.styles:
                    if dest_style.name == style.name:
                        style_exists = True
                        break
                if not style_exists:
                    dest_style = copy.styles.add_style(style.name, docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
                    dest_style.base_style = style
            elif style.type == docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER:
                style_exists = False
                for dest_style in copy.styles:
                    if dest_style.name == style.name:
                        style_exists = True
                        break
                if not style_exists:
                    dest_style = copy.styles.add_style(style.name, docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
                    dest_style.base_style = style

        new_section = copy.add_paragraph(para.text)
        new_section.style = para.style.name

        for next_para in doc.paragraphs[i+1:]:
            if next_para.style.name.startswith("Heading 1"):
                break
            new_section = copy.add_paragraph(next_para.text)
            new_section.style = next_para.style.name

        copy.save(f"example_doc_seccion{count}.docx")

        count += 1
```